# If I delete my wordpress site then does that delete all my sites?

Tags: customization

I have 2 wordpress sites, I didn't mean to but create 2 but i did. My main wordpress site I do not want deleted but If i delete the add on site i did not want (I know how to delete sites), will it delete my main site also?

Comment: Are these separate installs? Is this a multisite? Do they share the same database? Is this wordpress.com or self hosted? Your question cannot be answered with the information provided, please provide more for potential answers

Comment: This sounds like a cPanel/Web Hosting question, not really a WordPress question.  You might want to add more detail or ask the question somewhere more appropriate.